# How can I set a style once for multiple TabItems in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF but I would think there is a way that I can set multiple TabItems to use the same Style without adding the Style to each TabItem individually. Like I have done in the first TabItem. Is this possible?

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tabControl" Margin="5,0,5,5" Height="600" Width="998">
   <TabItem x:Name="tabSetToRun" Header="Run" Style="{DynamicResource myTabItemStyle}"/>

   <TabItem x:Name="tabShortcut" Header="Freeze Shortcut"/>
   <TabItem x:Name="tabFullAccess" Header="Full Access"/>
   <TabItem x:Name="tabOldForms" Header="Old Forms"/>
   <TabItem x:Name="tabCFG" Header="CFG Files"/>
</TabControl>
```

My Style for TabItems is:

```
     <Style x:Key="myTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="180"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            Background="#FF293955"
                            BorderBrush="LightCyan"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"                                    
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource lookup happens from the element upward in the visual tree.
If a `Style` doesn't have an `x:Key` it will be applied to all types of `TargetType`.

```
<Window x:Class="TabItemMultiple.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabItemMultiple"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="180"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            Background="#FF293955"
                            BorderBrush="LightCyan"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"                                    
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tabControl" Margin="5,0,5,5" Height="600" Width="998">
            <TabItem x:Name="tabSetToRun" Header="Run" />

            <TabItem x:Name="tabShortcut" Header="Freeze Shortcut"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="tabFullAccess" Header="Full Access"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="tabOldForms" Header="Old Forms"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="tabCFG" Header="CFG Files"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Remove the `x:Key` from your `Style`. If you put the `Style` in the `Resources` collection of your `Window` it changes the `TabItem`s in that `Window`.

Similarly if you put it in your `Application`'s `Resources` collection, then they will be changed in the whole application.

You can do this too, if you don't want every `TabItem` to be changed in the `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="TabItemMultiple.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabItemMultiple"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="180"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            Background="#FF293955"
                            BorderBrush="LightCyan"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"                                    
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tabControl" Margin="5,0,5,5" Height="600" Width="998">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource myTabItemStyle}" />
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem x:Name="tabSetToRun" Header="Run" />

            <TabItem x:Name="tabShortcut" Header="Freeze Shortcut"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="tabFullAccess" Header="Full Access"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="tabOldForms" Header="Old Forms"/>
            <TabItem x:Name="tabCFG" Header="CFG Files"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that the `x:Key` is now back and we use the `BasedOn`.

[image: Result]

Comment: When I use <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource myTabItemStyle}" /> I get an error: Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies

Comment: Yes, you can't change the `Style` from a `Style`. I meant copy your `<Setter .... />`s from `myTabItemStyle` into the new `Style` here: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"> ....... </Style>`. Please update the question with the definition of `myTabItemStyle`.

Comment: So are you saying I should add all the Style info under the tabControl directly? Using your  <TabControl.Resources>?

Comment: Ahhh I see. I removed the x:Key="myTabItemStyle" and that did the trick. I also now better understand how it all fits together. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on answers yet, but the following will also work.  It's based on Szabolcs's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34912002/5786449

It's slightly simpler, doesn't require a key on your style and still only apply to this instance of `TabItem`.  But it's less reusable.

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tabControl" Margin="5,0,5,5" Height="600" Width="998">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="180"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            Background="#FF293955"
                            BorderBrush="LightCyan"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"                                    
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSetToRun" Header="Run" />
    <TabItem x:Name="tabShortcut" Header="Freeze Shortcut"/>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabFullAccess" Header="Full Access"/>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabOldForms" Header="Old Forms"/>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabCFG" Header="CFG Files"/>
</TabControl>
```